# How can I access variables of a sub-class?

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance

```
public class Girl extends Student{...} //has firstname, lastname, id
public class Student {...}
public class School{
      Student[] arr = new girl(firstname, lastname, id)
      for(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
            arr.getID(); //does this work if I have a getter in Girl class?
}
}
```

If I have a Student array of girl objects, is it possible to access the girl's id from School class?

Comment: Why doesn't `Student` have those properties? First name, last name, and id would seem to be common attributes for all students.

Answer (score 1):

you can check

```
if (arr[i] instanceof Girl)
{
    Girl girl = (Girl)arr[i];
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly call getID() Student object. You must cast that Student object to Girl object, then you can access it with Girl class methods.

Answer (score 0):

first of all,you need new serverl girls for padding Student[] arr。

```
Student[] arr = new Student[num];
arr[0] = new girl();
arr[1] = new girl();
etc..
```

then access girl's field with a getter throw using

```
arr[i].getter
```

hopes that solve your problem.